# Timeout Exception error when making a Transactional operation with Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions, mybatis, websphere-liberty

I am involved in a new project and I was assigned to investigate an error that is happening when apparently a transaction(or more than one) to the database in being performed. We are using Java for the backend(Spring framework), MyBatis for mapping objects and Websphere Liberty as server, the problem comes in some methods that are marked as @Transactional, this is the declaration:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

Inside the method there are some executions to the database and apparently in some cases throws a TimeoutException and makes Rollback of operation, I guess concurrent calls make this(I am not sure) this is the error image we got:

[image: Error]

I am new in transactions and I don´t know if the parameters declared could affect in the performance, what can cause a TimeoutException as this?
I am lost, I would be grateful with any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Which connection pool you are using?

Comment: @igreen I asked to another developer and he told me that the connection pool is managed by the server, Websphere Liberty, I dont know how can I check that.

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7958867/1996296 let me know if it help you.