# Trying to create a new table column in DashDB but getting a timeout error

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

My problem is pretty much the same as here

[DB2 deadlock timeout Sqlstate: 40001, reason code 68 due to update statements called from servlet using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957887/db2-deadlock-timeout-sqlstate-40001-reason-code-68-due-to-update-statements-ca)

The problem is that I am using dashDB which runs as a service in IBM Cloud (formerly known as bluemix), so I don't have access to the same administrative tools some DB2 DBA has access to (AFAIK).

So I have a simple table, but when I try to add a column, I get this error

> SQL0911N: SQL0911N The current transaction has been rolled back
>   because of a deadlock or timeout. Reason code "68". SQLSTATE=40001
>   [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0911N The current transaction has
>   been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout. Reason code "68".
>   SQLSTATE=40001

I've stopped all other DB activity such as other select statements, and I've tried using eclipse JDBC-based DB IDE instead of the web-based administrative DashDB provided by IBM Cloud (just because its authentication session just ends too quickly) without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and post if it works. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21440972